# Can't find specific SSRS object

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In my report, I'm getting an error on "textbox 23'...

```
The value expression for the textrun 'Textbox23.Paragraphs[8].TextRuns[1]' contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.
```

For the life of me, I can't find Text box 23... Is there anyway to search for an object?

Comment: Try checking the XML definition of your report, look for Textbox23 in the any text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the properties menu, and click on the dropdown it will show you all your text boxes.[image: Picture]

Comment: I may have improperly tagged.. is this an SSRS 2012 only feature?

Comment: I am using ssrs2008 r2 go to VIEW > Properties Window.

Comment: Hit F4 and it should pop it up.

Comment: Weird, I do not seem to have dropdown functionality.  Regardless, i did find Textbox23

Comment: Any idea what the error message I am getting insinuates?

Comment: Can you post the expression?

Comment: Look at the following post to see if it is relevant to the expression you are having trouble with: http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/05/ssrs-rsruntimeerrorinexpression-value.html